# raise AppRegistryNotReady Error when run django models.py using pycharm

Tags: python, django, api

I am a new django, I am trying to write a post api, but when I run the models.py using pycharm, there is an error about class `Event(models.Model)`.
the error details as below.

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "F:/Auto_Projects/pydj/guest/sign/models.py", line 6, in 
>       class Event(models.Model):
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 110, in **new**
>       app_config = apps.get_containing_app_config(module)
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 247, in get_containing_app_config
>       self.check_apps_ready()
>     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 125, in check_apps_ready
>       raise AppRegistryNotReady("Apps aren't loaded yet.")
>   django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.

django version:1.11.14
python version:2.7

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
  'django.contrib.admin',
  'django.contrib.auth',
  'django.contrib.contenttypes',
  'django.contrib.sessions',
  'django.contrib.messages',
  'django.contrib.staticfiles',
  'sign', 
  'bootstrap3',
]
```

My app name is 'sign', and I have added the 'sign' to the `INSTALLED_APP` of the settings.py.

Comment: consider adding more information in the form of your code

Answer (score 0):

In django you run `manage.py` not `models.py`.  e.g.,

```
python manage.py runserver
```